# Duplicate Lists between subsites in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a site in sharepoint 2013 on my client. This site has the following structure

- Country 1

  - pt-br

    - subsite1
    - subsite2
    - subsite3

      - subsubsite1

        - list 1
        - list 2
        - list 3
      - subsubsite2

        - subsubsubsite1

          - list 4
          - list 5
  - es-es

    - subsite1
    - subsite2
    - subsite3

      - subsubsite1

        - list 1
        - list 2
        - list 3
      - subsubsite2

        - subsubsubsite1

          - list 4
          - list 5
  - en-us

    - subsite1
    - subsite2
    - subsite3

      - subsubsite1

        - list 1
        - list 2
        - list 3
      - subsubsite2

        - subsubsubsite1

          - list 4
          - list 5

It has this structure for 10 different countries in the sharepoint site. The problem is, I need to copy all this lists between all the countries' sites. Manually, it's take too much time and is vulnerable to series of errors. So I need to make this systemically, there is some powershell script who I can make this copy?

Answer (score 0):

Use Export-SPWeb and Import-SPWeb powershell commands

Export-SPWeb http://site -Path "site export.cmp"

Import-SPWeb http://site -Path export.cmp -UpdateVersions Overwrite